# DAX PowerBI Minimum Date Grouped By Client Responsive to Filters By User

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a SQL background and I'm trying to learn DAX. Basically, I have a query in a dataset where I need to get the earliest date corresponding to each row, for the same client (grouped by client), and I need a date filter for no dates earlier than a cutoff. I also need it to respond to user filters in the report - (where they will select by program - maybe I need a measure here?).

I really have no idea how to construct this in DAX.

To summarize: For every row (each row is a Service Case), there needs to be  the date of that Service Case (ServiceStart) but also the earliest Service Start for Service Cases of the same client, starting after a specific date, while dynamically responding to program-specific filters on the UI side of the report.

The Query in SQL looks something like this:

[Data In SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2uDI.png)

As you can see on Row 4 there are two different dates, because this client actually had an earlier Service Case date in another row in the table.

I am open to all suggestions for a best solution.

Comment: DAX is highly dependent on the data model - please post it. Data samples and example of the desired outcome will be very helpfull too.

Comment: Hey Andrew, welcome. Can you please post a shot of your data model and maybe some samples of what you would like?